# How do I enable a scanner in Ubuntu Server 23.10?

Tags: usb, scanner, sane

Prior to the server crash that led to rebuilding my server from scratch, I had my Epson Perfection V370 working over the network.  I have a vague recollection of entering the USB bus and device into a config file but I have no idea which one.  The scanner is shown when I run sudo scanimage -L but not just scanimage -L.  Any insights or hints welcome!